# Is there an emulator for a Windows Universal tablet in Visual Studio Preview 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I have installed, Visual Studio 2015 preview, and have begun playing around with Universal Apps.

I would like to see how the app looks on a tablet, but the only options I'm given are for phones.

[image]

If I select `Device` I get this error in the output window

> SmartDeviceException - Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.

If I select `Download New Emulators`, I get directed to [This Page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46893), and when I run the setup file downloaded from It, All I get is a window that says:

> The features installed on this computer are up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

If you run on Windows 10 then there is a simulator which can simulate various tablet resolutions and touch input.

The emulators are for mobile (phone) devices only.

Comment: Do you have a link for the simulator as opposed to the emulator?  It is the emulators which keep coming up in the pesky Google searches?

Answer (score 0):

You can now install the visual studio 2015RC which is available now.
Make sure that you installed the UAP(universal app platform) sdk form

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/install-dev-tools-visual-studio-2015

now you should be able to get a simulator which will help you to see how your app looks in a tablet.You can change various settings like size,resolution..etc.

Comment: That's what I did when I downloaded VS 2015.  If I didn't do that would I even have the phone emulators?